# How to draw separator in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I want to design like below:

[image]

**I designed with approach - single row with relative layout as root and than View as a separator. But on run its not showing separator. 
Please help me with some approach, how to design it.**

Code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">



  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/outline_with_white_background">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:text="Lead Name:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/follow_up_text_size"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/splash_status_color"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_text"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/label"
        android:text="Lead Name:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/tv_lead_name_label"
        android:textSize="@dimen/follow_up_text_size"
        />

 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/textview"
        android:id="@+id/tv_lead_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/follow_up_text_size"
        android:text="ARN"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/label"
        android:text="Lead Source:"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/tv_lead_source_label"
        android:textSize="@dimen/follow_up_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_name_label"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/textview"
        android:id="@+id/tv_lead_source"
        android:text="ARN"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_name_label"
        android:textSize="@dimen/follow_up_text_size"
        />


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Showing below on run :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an workaround:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_lead_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Lead Name:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_lead_name_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:text="test08"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_lead_source"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Lead Source:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_lead_source_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="OPD"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_lead_created"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Lead Created:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_lead_created_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="6/6/2017 12:00:00 PM"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_HV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="HV Fixed By:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_HV_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="DNC"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_EDD"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="EDD:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_EDD_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="12/12/2017 12:00:00 PM"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_city"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="City:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_city_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="DELHI"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_home_status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Home Status:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_home_status_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Follow-Up"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_follow_up"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Follow-up Date:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_follow_up_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="12/12/2017 12:00:00 PM"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_priority"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Priority:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_priority_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="HOT"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_activity_status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Activity Status:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_activity_status_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="Done"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_follow_up_created"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Follow-up Created:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_follow_up_created_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="12/12/2017 12:00:00 PM"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_multiline"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Multiline Example:"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_multiline_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ultricies fringilla augue dictum congue"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: If my answer helps and seems useful then please mark this as right answer and vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the separator height wrap_content to match_parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_name_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lead Name:"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_source_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_name_label"
                    android:text="Lead Source:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_created_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_source_label"
                    android:text="Lead Created:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_hv_fixed_by_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_created_label"
                    android:text="HV Fixed By:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_edd_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_hv_fixed_by_label"
                    android:text="EDD:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_city_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_edd_label"
                    android:text="City:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_home_status_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_city_label"
                    android:text="Home Status:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_Follow_up_date_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_home_status_label"
                    android:text="Follow-up Date:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_priority_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Follow_up_date_label"
                    android:text="Priority:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_activity_status_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_priority_label"
                    android:text="Activity Status:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_follow_up_created_label"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_activity_status_label"
                    android:text="Follow-up Created:"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="5.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_name"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_source"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_name_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lead_created"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_source_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_hv_fixed_by"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_created_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_edd"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_hv_fixed_by_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_city"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_edd_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_home_status"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_city_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_follow_up_date"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_home_status_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_priority"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Follow_up_date_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_activity_status"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_lead_priority_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_follow_up_created"
                    style="@style/textview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_activity_status_label"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="ARN"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            android:gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lead Name"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Left text suppose to be corresponding to right text. Hence, if i  use linear then if any text bigger then alignment gets disturb.

Comment: ya you are right than you must separate each with single view

Comment: Thats why i am troubling. ):

Comment: you can use single separator because if you want a single separator than it create a problem

Answer (score 0):

just change layout_height of your View and Linearlayout to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Hello"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:gravity="end"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Hello"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Hello"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:gravity="end"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Hello"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


        </GridLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLeadName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lead_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLeadNameText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lead_source"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lead_create"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/hv_fixed"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/edd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/city"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/home_status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/follow_up"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/priority"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"

                android:text="@string/actiivty_status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/follow_up_created"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try the code first then you will be understood easily